# Saving a complete dataframe to pdf in R

Tags: r

I'm looking to save a dataframe called chla.output (~100 rows, 2 columns) to a pdf in R/Rstudio.  I've been using:

```
  pdf(file = "output.pdf")
  grid.table(chla.output)
  dev.off()
```

Unfortunately when I open the pdf it only saves, say, the last 30 rows.  I also get the "null device 1" message in the console.  I'm sure there's an easy solution using RMarkdown, unfortunately I'm limited to only using base R or Rstudio because of the target audience for the package this is part of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your `data.frame` so I'm using `mtcars`.

Using the `height` argument of `pdf()` you can specify the document height. You want to adjust this value based on the number of rows your `data.frame` has. Dividing the number of rows by 3 seems to create a value that works well.

```
pdf(file = "output.pdf", height=nrow(mtcars)/3)
gridExtra::grid.table(mtcars)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Brilliant lol!  The original issue was the dataframe is variable, so sometimes it could be 100 rows long, and others only 4.